# Contents of h:head are not getting updated while using template in JSF (ICEFACES)

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Requirement: 
Adding javascript file for a given page (which uses templates).

Details: 
After successful login, user is navigated to a page, where he can perform different actions. 
I have used common template in all the pages (apart from login page). 
The template contains head tag, code for including header, footer and body (in which dynamic content will be included).

I observed that contents of head tag of the template are not getting updated (i.e. title tag, script tag). 
The contents of head tag remains same as that of login page and also the URL of my browser.

Can you please let me know the possible cause for above.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the fact partial updates require id of a tag to be updated and html head element does not support id. There is no address in the html to apply update to. Icefaces are using partial updates heavily. You can try to enforce full update upon interaction which triggers changes to head element.